# Using getters in Angular Component Templates?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-changedetection

Suppose we have a getter defined like this:

```
  get sku() {
    return this.form.get('sku').value
  }
```

And we use it like this:

```
    <mat-hint *ngIf="!sku">Example sku123</mat-hint>
```

Is there a better way of doing this from an Angular Change detection performance perspective?

We could use an `Observable`.  Something like this I think (Roughing this out):

```
sku$ = this.form.get('sku').valueChanges().pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
```

```
<mat-hint *ngIf="!(sku|async)">Example sku123</mat-hint>
```

Is one better than the other?

IIUC the getter will be called whenever there is change detection, but if we use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` with the `Observable` then will only receive notifications when the form updates?

Comment: [`untilDestroyed()`](https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy) is a third party solution. Might be worth to mention it in the question.

Comment: https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` will not apply the change to your sku in the view *ngIf because automatic change detection is deactivated now. Only the event will be triggered without changing the view. Therefore, you will have to explicitly invoke it using,

```js
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

this.form.valueChanges
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.cdRef.markForCheck();
    });
  }
```

```html
<mat-hint *ngIf="!sku">Example sku123</mat-hint>
```

Note: Performance will be increased by using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` as it only runs the cycle once. But will get complicated when it comes to reactive forms. And also all the child components inside the parent component using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` will be inherited and you will have to invoke them manually if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Getter is fine for the performance, except if the function is expensive as it will be called at each cycle. In this case, a pipe is preferred as the result is cached.